# Can I play multiple Idols one at a time and receive the effects each time?

Tags: dominion, dominion-nocturne

We just played [Dominion Nocturne](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Nocturne) and had the [Idol](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Idol) victory card in play for the first time. As you see it has an effect that depends on the number of Idols you have in play.

[image: Idol card]

From the [Dominion Strategy Wiki on Gameplay under Buy phase](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Gameplay) I read that:

> At the beginning of the buy phase, the player may play any number of Treasure cards from their hand, in any order, to their play area.

**Does this mean that at the start of my buy phase, if I have multiple Idols on my hand, I can play them one at a time and first receive a Boon, then deal a Curse to the other players, then receive another Boon, deal a Curse, etc. for as many Idols I have on my hand?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you play them one at a time, and therefore you get the alternating boon and curse effect.

Note that this mandatory, not merely an option: You always play (and resolve) your treasures one at a time. Usually order doesn't matter, so players tend to gloss over that protocol in practice. But the order is always there.

Answer (score 6):

Not only can you, but you MUST play them one at a time and receive the effects each time. While some players will short cut and play everything at once, technically cards are always played one at a time, resolved, then the next card is played. For most treasures there's not much difference, like the basic ones which only provide coin, or ones that also directly gain cards when played, like [Treasure Trove](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Treasure_Trove), but for treasures like [Idol](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Idol), [Bank](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Bank) and [Fortune](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Fortune) the order that they are played matters.

Comment: Venture is also super important order wise, especially if you are have any other treasures that order matters for!

Comment: @aslum because of others that may change the deck? Venture digs for the next treasure after all. I was only listing a few examples there, the list wasn't meant to be exhaustive.

Comment: Yeah, if I've got 5 copper and a Bank I can still toss 'em all down at once and figure out I've got 11$ pretty easy. Venture on the other hand will play a card from your deck, and the card played isn't optional, so Order of Operations is particularly important.

Comment: @aslum true, but technically playing those 6 cards could give you anywhere from 6 to 11 coins, obviously you'd want it done in the most beneficial order, but all those options do exist

Comment: The usual fight over Bank comes when there are more than one Banks. Bank wants to be played last, but when two are played, they can't both be played last (and each count the other). Sometimes this comes up "naturally" in the hand, and sometimes when a Bank is retrieved by a Venture (especially aggravating when it's the first Venture of several Ventures).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the start of the buy phase you may play as many treasures as you feel like, provided you have them in your hand.

Note that this is after you have finished your action phase so if you end up drawing action cards those are wasted.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you address OP's question about applying Curses and Boons specifically in your answer?